# AjaxControlToolkit AutoComplete Suggestions Showing at Wrong Position Due to Scroll Bar

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Autocomplete textbox which is inside a div with scrolling enabled. I add lots of textboxes dynamically inside the div which enables the vertical scrolling. When I scroll down and type in the auto suggest textbox then it appears waay above the correct location. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your autocompleted textbox with a relative positioned div.

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextBox" Width="300" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```